# Como añadir filas a una tabla creada en html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Esta es mi tabla que he creado en html es de 1x9, pero quiero añadir más filas a través de un combo. Quiero usar javascript. ¿Cómo puedo modificarlo?

*TABLA HTML*

```
  <table class="table">      
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">VALOR DEL INMUEBLE:</th>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control validarVI" name="valorinmueble" 
                id="valorinmueble"   
                onclick="validarcampos()"
                onblur="validarcampos()"
                placeholder="Ingrese el valor del inmueble" 
                tittle="Ingrese primero el valor del inmubele" required=" "  min="1">
        </td>
      </tr>
  
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">IMPORTE FINACIERO:</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="importefinanciero" disabled 
          id="importefinanciero"></td>
      </tr>
  
      <tr>           
       <th scope="row">IMPORTE A AHORRAR:</th>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="importeaahorrar"  disabled 
          id="importeaahorrar" ></td>      
       </tr>
  
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">PLAZO DE OPERACION:</th>
        <td>      
        <select id="plazooperacion" name="pro" class="form-select" required="" disabled onclick="return validarcampos();" onblur="visible()">                                      
              <option>24</option>
              <option>36</option>
              <option>48</option> 
              <option>60</option>
              <option>72</option>
              <option>84</option>                                                                                                            
              <option>96</option>
              <option>120</option>
              <option>144</option>
              <option>180</option>
              <option>240</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr> 
  
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

¿Cómo capto el valor del combo en javascript? (tiene valores de 24,36,48, son las cantidades de filas que quiero generar):

```
var plazooperacion= document.getElementById("plazooperacion").value;
```

He encontrado este código, para generar las tablas con javascript, pero quiero amoldarlo a la tabla que tengo en el html; que aparece en la siguiente página (también es html con javascript):

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces

Este código es de la web de arriba:

```
var table = document.getElementById("cuerpotabla");
var row = table.insertRow();
//this adds row in 0 index i.e. first place
row.innerHTML = "<tr><td>"+ms+"</td><td id='cuota' name ='cuota'>"+cuota+"</td><td id='interes' name='interes'>"+interes+"</td><td id='amorti' name='amorti'>"+amorti+
    "</td><td id='capital' name='capital'>"+capital+"</td><td id='segurodesgrav' name='segurodesgrav'>"+segurodesgrav+"</td><td  id='seguroinmobil' name='seguroinmobil'>"+seguroinmobil+"</td><td id='gastosadm' name='gastosadm'>"+gastosadm+"</td><td id='cuotafinal' name='cuotafinal'>"+cuotafinal+"</td></tr>";
```

Pero me genera más filas de las que necesito. ¿Cómo puedo meter el valor del combo al codigo de arriba?

En la imagen estoy probando que solo me genere 24 filas

[image: Imagen de como se me genera]

Comment: Muéstranos lo que has realizado hasta ahora para poderte ayudar.  Aquí no hacemos código a medida, sino que solucionamos problemas de código generado por los que preguntan, y en tu caso no veo que hayas hecho nada, tan solo dices lo que quieres sin ni tan siquiera haberlo intentado, o no lo muestras al menos. Preséntanos lo que has realizado, donde te has encallado y que errores obtuvistes, y podremos ayudarte, gracias.

Comment: Ya añadí la porción de js que uso para que me genere las filas, solo me importa por el momento la cantidad de filas

Comment: Y ese codigo esta escrito donde en tu pagina? si genera mas filas, es porque le estas diciendo en algun lado que lo haga...

Comment: ¿Dónde está el bucle actual que te genera la repetición de las 24 filas varias veces?  Nos has mostrado "parte" del código pero, aparte de lo que quieres, que es pasarle el valor del combo al bucle, necesitamos verlo para ayudarte mejor y saber como lo estás haciendo ahora para ayudarte a arreglarlo.  Si está en el enlace que has puesto piensa que no podemos ayudarte, pues lo queremos ver todo en la pregunta (no voy a enlaces externos a ver nada normalmente). Los enlaces externos pueden caducar y la pregunta perderia contexto con el tiempo.